# c#-tesseract get space recoginition in digits

Tags: c#, tesseract

I am new in tesseract and I am making a class project in which I need to scan number matrices. I have been successful in reading numbers from an image file but I haven't found yet how to recognize spacing between digits. For example currently I am getting 14610 for 1  4  6 10.

Image:

[image]

Code I am currently using:

```
Bitmap myBmp = new Bitmap(file);
var image = myBmp;
var ocr = new Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only 

ocr.Init(@"C:\Users\MuhammadShahroz\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\tessdata", "eng", false);
var results = ocr.DoOCR( image, Rectangle.Empty);

foreach (Word word in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
    mystring = String.Format("{0 } ",word.Text);
}
```

Comment: Looking at other examples of whitelists, I see they include space in the list. Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will need to set variable `preserve_interword_spaces=1` (see [configuration source](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/d72c2b14a5805952cc01fd99ec64f7abd99ca47c/src/ccmain/tesseractclass.h#L1000))

Comment: How to install this patch can you help?

Comment: This should be supported in 3.0.4 and later. The commit for the patch is [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/commit/36883b4fafcd69135308a3fb15a4398ec40d9dea).

Comment: There is still no difference.
I have used it like: 
var ocr = new Tesseract();                    ocr.SetVariable("preserve_interword_spaces","1");

Comment: Make sure you use tesseract.net [3.0.0](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/releases) or greater as it is compatible with Tesseract 3.04.

Comment: It seems the inter-spacing has to be large enough for Tesseract to detect after setting that variable.